# macos arm64 flutter builds

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos

I have an problem building hello world flutter project for arm64 (apple m1 pro silicon) macos platform:

```
$ flutter build macos
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application_1...              234ms

 Building with sound null safety 

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006000-000C09201A06801E }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006000-000C09201A06801E }
Snapshot not compatible with the current VM configuration: the snapshot requires 'release no-code_comments no-dwarf_stack_traces_mode lazy_async_stacks lazy_dispatchers no-dedup_instructions no-asserts use_field_guards use_osr no-branch_coverage x64-sysv no-compressed-pointers no-null-safety' but the VM has 'release no-code_comments no-dwarf_stack_traces_mode lazy_async_stacks lazy_dispatchers no-dedup_instructions no-asserts use_field_guards use_osr no-branch_coverage arm64-sysv no-compressed-pointers no-null-safety'


Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
** BUILD FAILED **

Building macOS application...                                           
Build process failed
```

Unfortunately I'm not an expert on flutter and flutter build tools, but it seems that flutter builds x86_64 binary and tries to run it on aarch64 platform for some reason. How can I make flutter to build aarch64 version of app?

Template project built with command:

```
flutter create --template app --platforms macos hello_world
```

Tools version info:

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 3.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 85684f9300 (3 months ago) • 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
Engine • revision 6ba2af10bb
Tools • Dart 2.17.5 • DevTools 2.12.2
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.1
BuildVersion:   21C52
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 13.0
Build version 13A233
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was with the way I've installed flutter: nixpkgs. It tries to find tools in wrong folder. After modifying patches https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/196133 for macos everything works fine.